# Camel FTP recursive consumer taking too long

Tags: java, recursion, ftp, apache-camel

I am trying to retrieve files from only certain subdirectories on an FTP server .  For example, I want to poll for files under only subdirectories A and C.

```
ROOT_DIR/A/test1.xml
ROOT_DIR/B/test2.xml
ROOT_DIR/C/test3.xml
ROOT_DIR/..(there are hundreds of subdirs)
```

I'm trying to avoid having an endpoint for each directory since many more directories to consume from may be added in the future.

I have successfully implemented this using a single SFTP endpoint on ROOT_DIR with recursive=true [in conjunction with an AntPathMatcherGenericFileFilter instance as suggested](http://camel.apache.org/ftp2#FTP2-FilteringusingANTpathmatcher).

The issue I'm having is that every subdirectory is being search (hundreds of them) and my filter is also looking for certain filenames only.  The result is only filtered after every directory is searched and this is taking far too long (minutes).

Is there any way to only consume from certain subdirectories that could be maintained in a properties file without searching every subdirectory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find one possible solution using a different approach using a [Timer Based Polling Consumer](http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html#PollingConsumer-TimerBasedPollingConsumer) with the Ant filter.  With this solution, a dynamic sftp endpoint (or list of dynamic sftp endpoints) can be consumed from using a ConsumerTemplate inside a bean instead of doing so within a route.

```
while (true) {
            // receive the message from the queue, wait at most 3 sec
            String msg = consumer.receiveBody("activemq:queue.inbox", 3000, String.class);
.
.
```

This can then be used with my existing Ant filter to select only certain files under a dynamic list of subdirectories to consume from.